# How to make MonoGame's background transparent?

Tags: uwp, monogame, spine

I have a UWP App and I use SwapChainPanel to insert MonoGame.
in Render():

```
_game.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);
```

But it didn't work.

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <SwapChainPanel x:Name="swapChainPanel">
    </SwapChainPanel>
</Grid>
```

Could you help me to figure out it?
[Problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8ywb.png)

Comment: Could you provide us the code about your `_game` type?

Comment: [**_game_Code**](https://github.com/Aloento/SuperSpineViewer-Sharp-/blob/master/SuperSpineViewer/Views/MonoPlay.cs)

Comment: @YanGu-MSFT I'm a freshman at C#, and there is my project repository.